# Setup Third party package into custom service provider

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to apply a sort of "repository-pattern" to a custom service.

What I'd like to do is to actually bind [this](https://github.com/alexpechkarev/google-maps) library to my custom service provider to create an abstraction layer and, eventually, switch that library with another one in the future.

I'm trying to move the `'providers'` and `'aliases'` references from `config/app.php` to my service provider, but I get a `Class 'GoogleMaps' not found` error.

I've added `App\Providers\GeoServiceProvider::class` to `config/app.php` providers array and this is my relevant code:

`GeoServiceProvider.php`(my custom service provider)

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class GeoServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(\App\Interfaces\GeoInterface::class, \App\Services\GoogleGeoService::class);

        $this->app->alias(\GoogleMaps\Facade\GoogleMapsFacade::class, 'GoogleMaps');
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

    }
}
```

`GeoInterface.php`interface defining standard methods

```
<?php
namespace App\Interfaces;


interface GeoInterface
{
    public function geoCode();
}
```

`GoogleGeoService.php`(The actual library implementation)

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Interfaces\GeoInterface;


class GoogleGeoService implements GeoInterface
{
    public function geoCode()
    {
        $response = \GoogleMaps::load( 'geocoding' ) <--- HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
            ->setParamByKey( 'latlng', "45.41760620,11.90208370")
            ->setEndpoint( 'json' )
            ->get();
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

`TestController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Interfaces\GeoInterface;

class TestController extends Controller
{

    protected $geoService;

    public function __construct(GeoInterface $geoService) {
        $this->geoService = $geoService;
    }

    public function index() {
        return $this->geoService->geoCode();
    }
}
```

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: See if [this](https://medium.com/@basantbesra/create-aliases-for-your-classes-in-laravel-6814c349d3af)  helps

Comment: Thank you, I’ve read the article but what I’d like to do is to define the facade into the `GeoServiceProvider` (not in config/app.php). In this way I could switch the actual api library with another one. I’ve tried to define it with `$this->app->alias(\GoogleMaps\Facade\GoogleMapsFacade::class, 'GoogleMaps')` but it doesn’t work: I get a `Class 'GoogleMaps' not found` error.

Comment: Can you try `composer dump-autoload` once?

Comment: I've tried: same error. If I instantiate that class `$googleMaps = new \GoogleMaps\GoogleMaps();
        $response = $googleMaps->load( 'geocoding' )
            ->setParamByKey( 'latlng', "45.41760620,11.90208370")
            ->setEndpoint( 'json' )
            ->get();` it just works. But why I cannot use the facade?

Comment: Is there conflict between the third party package and your own GeoServiceProvider bindings. Try with a different name for the alias maybe.
Also can you post the full error response.

Comment: Hi, tried to change che alias name but the problem remains -> `Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'TestGoogleMaps' not found`